# How to add tap listener to the displayed image and bind XY axis to the image

Tags: android, image, listener, coordinates, tap

I would like to display an `.jpg` image into the screen and add `Listener` to this image which will can detect the location of tap on that image. I would like to bind XY axis to the image.

Example:

[image]

To display an image I should use:

```
private ImageView imgView;
imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewId);
imgView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile("pathToImageFile"));
```

To add listener to the image

```
iv.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
```

But how to define that listener which will detect the click coordinates `(x,y)` but the coordinates should be binded to the image not to the screen.

Comment: See View.setOnTouchListener()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    ImgeView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch(event.getAction()){
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                //Finger placed on screen
                event.getX();  
                event.getY();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                //Finger is moving
                event.getX();
                event.getY();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                //Second finger is touching screen
                break;
            }
            return false;
        }

    });
```